# Weird Regex Match

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have the following Regex:

```
Regex.IsMatch(someString, "[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]")
```

I wanted that `someString` to only allow a form like `x.y` where `x > 0` and `0 <= y <= 9`.
But it won't work as excepted, an example:

```
someString = "1.02"
Regex.IsMatch(someString, "[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]")
```

Equals in `true`, but that can't be
I also tried another Regex:

```
Regex.IsMatch(someString, "[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]{1}")
```

But it made no difference... or is there something missing in my pattern?

Comment: 0 >= y >= 9 can't be right...because y must be negative and greater than 9 at the same time which simply doesn't work out. Describe again which values you want y to be please.

Comment: I note that your regex strings are invalid because the `\.` will report as an "Unrecognised escape sequence". You should make sure that the code you provide is completing working. :)

Comment: @Igle: I think you may need to reread it. I'm not sure where you get x must be negative and greater than 9 from and y being a single digit (which is what this says basically) seems fine to me.

Comment: Should be ``0 <= y <= 9``, I mixed it up sorry.

Comment: 0 >= y >= 9 is simply a equation that has no solution for y. The author just corrected this in his question to 0 <= y <= 9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the start-of-line `^` and end-of-line `$` anchors here or you will get partial matches like in your case, change to:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]$
```

Your original expression matched a portion of `1.02` which is `1.0` and though it was valid and it is actually valid when taken alone, the anchors prevent the expression from matching partial strings and forces the entire expression to match.